# Laravel ReactJS Post Method Not Allowed

Tags: laravel, reactjs, laravel-5.5

I know there are lots of solution for this kind of problem that I'm having. But I think I have almost tried most of them and none works.

My experience with PHP Laravel is quite good but not with front-end libraries or framework such as VueJS or ReactJS. I am planning to expand my knowledge with front-end part with ReactJS.

I have created a sample project that is food ordering system. These are the tables:-

**User migration table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Food migration table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('foods', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->default('');
            $table->boolean('in_stock')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Food_user migration table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('food_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('quantity');
            $table->boolean('is_served')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My routes and related controller:-

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('food', 'FoodController');

Route::get('/allfood', 'FoodController@index');

Route::post('/addfood', 'FoodController@create');

// Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function($router){
//     Route::post('/addfood', 'FoodController@create');
// });
```

**FoodController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Food;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FoodController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(Food::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $newfood = Food::create([
            'name' => request('foodname'),
            'description' => request('fooddesc'),
            'in_stock' => 1,
        ]);

        return response()->json(Food::all());
    }
}
```

I can display the seeded data well with `axios`

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Food from './Food';

export default class Main extends Component {

    constructor() {

    super();

    this.state = {
        foods: [],
        currentPage: 1,
    }

  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: 'http://localhost:8000/allfood'
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ foods: response.data });
        });
  }

    renderFoods() {
        return this.state.foods.map(foods => {
            return (
                <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" key={foods.id}>
                    <div className="panel panel-default">
                        <div className="panel-heading">{ foods.name }</div>
                        <div className="panel-body">
                            { foods.description }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })
    }

    changePage(pagenum) {
        this.setState({currentPage:pagenum});
    }

    render() {

        switch(this.state.currentPage) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <div className="container-fluid" style={{marginTop: 50 + 'px'}}>
                        <div className="top-right links">
                            <a href="#" onClick={() =>this.changePage(2)}>Add Food</a>
                            <a href="#" onClick={() =>this.changePage(1)}>Order Food</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row text-center">
                            <h2>List of Menu</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            { this.renderFoods() }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
                break;
            case 2:
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div className="container-fluid" style={{marginTop: 50 + 'px'}}>
                            <div className="top-right links">
                                <a href="#" onClick={() =>this.changePage(2)}>Add Food</a>
                                <a href="#" onClick={() =>this.changePage(1)}>Order Food</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Food/>
                    </div>
                );
                break;        }
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('main')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('main'));
}
```

But to add a new record (new food). Here I am stuck.

**Food.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Food extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            newFood: {
                name: '',
                description: '',
                instock: 0
            },
            foods: []
        }
    }

    submitMenu () {

        var foody = this.state.newFood;

        console.log(foody);

        var testpost = axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost:8000/addfood',
          data: {
            name: foody.name,
            description: foody.description,
            in_stock: foody.instock
          }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

        console.log(testpost);

    }


    handleInput(key, e) {

        var state = Object.assign({}, this.state.newFood); 
        state[key] = e.target.value;

        this.setState({newFood: state });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid" style={{marginTop: 50 + 'px'}}>
                <div className="row text-center">
                    <h2>Add Menu</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <div className="panel panel-default">
                            <div className="panel-body">
                                <form onSubmit={this.submitMenu.bind(this)} method="POST">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label>Food Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Food Name" name="foodname" onChange={(e)=>this.handleInput('name',e)}/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label>Food Description</label>
                                        <textarea className="form-control" name="fooddesc" onChange={(e)=>this.handleInput('description',e)}></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="instock" value="1"/> In Stock?
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I type new information in the form and submit. Laravel throws error:-

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ 
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

And when I check the browser's console log, here what I see:-

```
> Object { name: "Deep Fried Chicken", description: "Dipped with chill sauce", instock: 0 }
> Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

So what is the problem here? I have tried:-

1. Install and configure Laravel Cors to bypass CSRF.
2. Create a specific Laravel Cors middleware group.
3. Change method from POST to GET.
4. Remove (comment) `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` from 
   `kernel.php`.
5. Try hardcoding data at `axios`.

I suspect my usage of `axios` post method is not right. Still, I just follow the documentation.

This is my first experience on full javascript front-end development. And my knowledge of javascript is very very little. I hope my question here is proper and fully explained.....

Answer (score 0):

ur code is right, u just need to inform ur `create` method that has `Request` as param to get all data sent from ur `axios` code.

ur `create` would be like this and u need to return http success status code to ur client side code (201) :

for more information about http code read this article : [link](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)

```
/**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $newfood = Food::create([
            'name' => $request->get('foodname'),
            'description' => $request->get('fooddesc'),
            'in_stock' => 1,
        ]);

        //return response()->json(Food::all()); /* u don't need to return data here */
        return response()->json([],201);  
    }
```

Comment: It does not work... it return the same error... I think the problem is before it goes to Laravel back end... Which means it is `route`, `axios` or some security authentication problem that does not accept post from `axios`...